# Time/Data Conversion to Unix

Tags: python, date, unix, unix-timestamp

Im trying to convert a specific date to unix, but unfortunatelly something seems to be missing/wrong.
Any help, will be highly appreciated.

```
releasedate='Jul 07 2022 02:00:00'
releasedate2 = datetime.strptime(releasedate, '%b-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S')
unixdate = (releasedate2 - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: What is wrong or missing? Are you getting errors?

Comment: releasedate2 = datetime.strptime(releasedate, '%b-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Jul 07 2022 02:00:00' does not match format '%b-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S'

Comment: as far as i can understand, it says that it doesnt match the format, but i believe it does.

Comment: You have to use the correct format.

Comment: @nnaem please explain.

Comment: You have dashes while the date you have only has spaces, remove the dashes from your format and use spaces instead. That should fix it.

Comment: The format has to match the format of what you're giving it, so in your case: `'%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'` would work because your input date matches that format.

Comment: @nnaem like this? releasedate2 = datetime.strptime(releasedate, '%b%d%Y%H:%M:%S')

Comment: Can you mark my answer as solution please, also no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had used the wrong date and time format.

You used: `%b-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S` when the format of the date you have is `%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S`.

Answer (score 0):

The date format you are using does not match the format of the date.
You are using `-` but the date has a space.
change it to `'%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'`